# Alloy: unexpected instance, difference between Sig'=Sig & Sig.field' = Sig.field

Tags: modeling, alloy

I am trying to model the following properties:

- Given a computation rule, and an Observable (~asset) we may raise an alert for this pair of (rule, observable).
- User can disable some rules, and we won't raise alerts for them.

I have modelled it like so:

```
var sig Rule {}
var sig Disabled in Rule {}
sig Observable {}

var one sig State {
    var raised: Rule -> lone Observable
}

pred stutter {
    State' = State
}

pred raiseAlert[r: Rule, p: Observable] {
    // rule must not be disabled
    r not in Disabled
    (r -> p) not in State.raised
    State.raised' = State.raised + (r -> p)
    Rule' = Rule
}

pred muteRule[r: Rule] {
    // not yet in Disabled
    r not in Disabled
    Disabled' = Disabled + r
    // State.raised' = State.raised // this results in "No instance found" ?
    State' = State
}

pred liveness {
     (some r: Rule, p: Observable | raiseAlert[r, p])
    or (some r: Rule | muteRule[r])
}

fact next {
    always (liveness)
}

run liveness
```

Two questions:

1. Here, in State 1 somehow we end up we less "raised" than in State 0. However, I only ever specified how to *add* more raised alerts, never how to *remove* them. How is this possible?
   [image]

2. What's the difference between `"State' = State"` and `State.raised' = State.raised`? Replacing the first with the second, results in `No Instance found`, and I don't understand why?

EDIT:

```
var sig Rule {}
var sig Disabled in Rule {}
sig Observable {}

var one sig State {
    var raised: Rule -> lone Observable
}
fact {
    some Rule
    some Observable
}
pred stutter {
    State' = State
    State.raised' = State.raised
    Disabled' = Disabled
    Rule' = Rule
}

pred raiseAlert[r: Rule, p: Observable] {
    r not in Disabled
    (r -> p) not in State.raised
    State.raised' = State.raised + (r -> p)
    Rule' = Rule
    State' = State
    Disabled' = Disabled
}

pred muteRule[r: Rule] {
    r not in Disabled
    Disabled' = Disabled + r
    State' = State
    // remove those elements from raised which start with rule "r"
    State.raised' = State.raised - (r <: State.raised)
}

pred liveness_only_stutter {
    always ((some r: Rule, p: Observable | raiseAlert[r, p])
        or (some r: Rule | muteRule[r]) or stutter)
}

pred liveness_no_instances {
    always ((some r: Rule, p: Observable | raiseAlert[r, p])
        or (some r: Rule | muteRule[r]))
}

pred liveness_actually_interesting {
    // this one actually generates interesting instances
    (some r: Rule, p: Observable | raiseAlert[r, p])
        or (some r: Rule | muteRule[r])
}


run liveness_actually_interesting
```

After this edit:

- added a fact for some Rule, some Observable
- changed liveness from fact to predicate
- No more unexpected instances, but still, some predicates only ever stutter, and do anything useful.
- I had to remove `always` from my predicate to actually get useful stuff done
- `In particular, they may interact by preventing the existence of any trace or by only allowing finite traces. But Alloy only considers infinite traces as instances`: I have no idea what you are talking about. Feels like some magic rules coming out of secret places. Where I can read more about it? I don't think it's in the "Software Abstractions" book ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many comments are in order. First, I wouldn't call `liveness` the predicate representing possible traces. Usually we keep `liveness` for liveness properties we want to check, not properties we want to take as a fact.

With `next` as a fact, it doesn't seem really useful to `run liveness`, `run {}` will do.

Then, you have a `stutter` predicate but you don't say that this may happen as an event in the `next` fact.

Also notice, but maybe that was clear to you, that `State` may take various values among a finite number of values defined by the scope. The `one` attribute only says that it has exactly one value in every instant.

In `next` you allow `muteRule` to happen, and this event doesn't constrain `raised`. So, as explained just before, `raised` may change arbitrarily, which is what happens in your question 1.

Re question 2, if you have no instance for a `run`, it's because you have over-constrained your model. So you must look again at all constraints and think about how they may interact. In particular, they may interact by preventing the existence of any trace or by only allowing *finite* traces. But Alloy only considers *infinite* traces as instances (this is one reason to systematically add a `stutter` event in the `next` fact).

Now, assessing how events interact in your model is a bit hard because, as explained above, you haven't said what happens to every variable in every event (some frame conditions are missing). In `raiseAlert` for instance, anything may happen to `Disabled`, to `State`, and to `raised` on values other than `State`. So for instance, `raiseAlert` may increase the value of `State.raised` but decrease it for other states at the same time. Similarly for `muteRule`.

Please fix your model first, by stating explicitly what happens to every variable.

EDIT: Now that your model is edited, some comments.

Regarding "liveness", I was just pointing out that the name was badly chosen. But you can (and usually should) still define the predicate contents in a fact stating what are the possible traces, like this:

```
fact possible_traces {
always ((some r: Rule, p: Observable | raiseAlert[r, p])
        or (some r: Rule | muteRule[r]) or stutter)
}
```

Second, note that in your events, you only modify `raised` on `State`. Which means you allow `raised` to change for every other state value. I don't think this is what you mean in general. One way to say that `raised` changes *only* on `State` is rather to write:

```
raised' = raised - State -> r -> univ
```

This way, you effectively specify what happens to every tuple in `raised`.

Also you forgot to say what happens to `Rule` in `muteRule`.

Re the fact that you don't always get interesting instances, that's normal. Your system is now allowed to stutter, which is good in general, but a consequence is that you may also get "uninteresting" instances. But these are correct instances! To see other instances, you may use the `New ...` buttons in the Visualizer; you could also issue specific `run` commands; and you could finally (but that will need a bit more experience) add so-called "weak fairness" properties (which somehow force progress when it's possible).

Finally, regarding the question on traces. I was supposing you knew about that as you're using the `var` keyword which isn't Daniel Jackson's book either. This is specific to Alloy 6: please refer to [Formal Software Design with Alloy 6](https://haslab.github.io/formal-software-design/) for a tutorial-style on-going book.

Comment: I think I fixed all the forgotten variables, but I still don't understand how everything works together..

Comment: OK that's much better :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a very detailed answer, you cleared my many confusions. For example, I thought that since I declared "raised" within "State", then it only exists as "private member" and can't be accessed elsewhere. Also, thanks for the link: I had no idea the new documentation is on going